# How to change a unity UI Button's state in code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm now using unity 4.6,the new UI system , since i won't use mouse to control my game,could anyone tell me how can i change a button's state in script ?

Comment: I think you're going to have to give us more details about what it is you're trying to do and what you've tried.

Comment: I'm trying to use kinect to control my game , now i'm able to recognize gestures correctly,like push,swipe,etc. But i'm having problem using these gestures to interact with unity UI elements . Since i'm also a iOS developer,i thought the UIButton must have a variable like "highlighted" or "pressed" , so that i can use : button.pressed = true ;  when push gesture is detected , but I couldn't find any variable like that , so now i have no idea what to do .

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to start by trying to make your system work with keyboard, using the UI navigation system.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-SelectableNavigation.html

You could manually set a button to selected state by using EventSystem.Current.SetCurrentlySelectedGameobject(yourGameObject);

If this button has an onLeft/OnRight etc. value setted, you will be able to interact with it with input Horizontal vertical axis, and to press it with a "Submit" value in input manager.

Once you're happy with it, you should try to catch your kinnect gestures and use them to send correct events I guess.